# How to arrange elements vertically with flexbox and css

Tags: css

I have three elements in my HTML that I would like to arrange vertically (stacked if you will), regardless of size (which is dynamic for some of the elements).

I have tried using `flexbox` and the usual advice on the net but it does not seem to work.

```css
.intro {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #455934;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.recipe {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 400px;
  width: 75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: left;
}

.recipe a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #cda44c;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.recipe a:hover {
  color: white;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.recipe_image {
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe">
  <p class="intro">
    {{label}}
  </p>
  <a href='test.html'>
  Rezept von {{source}}
 </a>
  <br>
  <a href='test.html'>
    <img src='C:/users/fabian.nguyen/03 - Customer Analytics/Bots/Flask Test/static/rock.gif' alt="TEST" class="recipe_image">
  </a>
</div>
```

You can see the resulting HTML (rendered via Flask but that is not the issue) here:
https://nachhaltig-kochen.herokuapp.com/getrecipe

Instead of stacking into a column (1. Label 2. Text-Link 3. Image-Link) they arrange in a row of equally sized divs.

EDIT:

Thanks to Pete, the solution is simply to remove any flex box reference as the elements should (and do) naturally stack vertically without any other style.

Comment: if you just want them stacked, why apply flex?  Your html code as is should stack them anyway without adding additional styles to the parent.  Also on your site, you have not applied flex-direction

Comment: @Pete Spot on, that actually fixed it. I took the style with flex from a previous container who is similar but can contain more elements who should wrap in flex.